# Indexing a grid with row and column number?

Tags: qgis

Very new to QGIS. I'm using it to analyse agricultural field microplots for research.

I need to give each field plot its own object which I've done so by using the "create grid" tool. But I need to assign a column and row number to each object in the attribute table to make it easier to sort the data. This should start in the bottom left (1:1) and ascend in row for objects above (2:1) and ascend in column for objects to the right (1:2).

[image: This is where I am so far..]

I've orientated the grid to start in the bottom left and learned that by using @row_number, I can re-number the objects from 1 to the total number of objects. But I need to add column number and row number to the attribute table.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/408967/88814

Comment: Yeah, pretty much duplicate. The answer there's quite a bit more complex than necessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most accessible option here is using the [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) to add two integer columns to the attribute table. For a rectilinear grid with `cells_y` cells in the y direction (24 in this case) the expressions are something like

```
floor(("id" - 1) / cells_y) + 1
```

where `id` is the attribute table column with the cell number (set automatically by Vector -> Research Tools -> Create grid or, in the OP's case, to @rownumber).

For the y index it's

```
cells_y + 1 - if(("id" % cells_y) = 0, cells_y, "id" % cells_y)
```

This is for the ones based indexing asked for here; remove the + 1 bits for zero-based. Similarly, subtracting (as is done with y here) or not subtracting (x here) the modulus part flips the directions in which the cells are numbered. This approach can also be used in PyQGIS.

There's a few [grid plugins](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/grid/) for QGIS and several similar StackOverflow questions (like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228424/creating-indexed-vector-grid-in-qgis)) which may also be of interest.